# Sticky footer in List SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a sticky footer in a List View in SwiftUI

It doesn't seem to operate the same as the header per say. This is an example of a sticky header implementation

```
     List {
      ForEach(0..<10) { index in
        Section(header: Text("Hello")) {
          ForEach(0..<2) { index2 in
            VStack {
              Rectangle().frame(height: 600).backgroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
          }
        }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
      }
    }
```

This above gives a sticky header situation. Although, once I change `Section(header: ...` to `Section(footer:...` it doesn't seem to be sticky anymore, it's simply places at the end of the row.

A more explicit reference

```
 List {
  ForEach(0..<10) { index in
    Section(footer: Text("Hello")) {
      ForEach(0..<2) { index2 in
        VStack {
          Rectangle().frame(height: 600).backgroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
      }
    }.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Comment: Updated question for a more explicit reference.

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Haven't got a solution as of yet, I did find a library https://github.com/zenangst/Blueprints which has a sticky footer, but this is in UI-Kit not SwiftUI. Other then that not much progress

Comment: Ok..Thank you :)

Comment: @Zeona with iOS 14 we can use Lazy... to achieve this. Please see answer for more

Comment: Thank you :) will try your solution :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest on SwiftUI (2) we now have access to a few more API's

For starters we can use a `LazyVStack` with a `ScrollView` to give us pretty good performance, we can then use the `pinnedViews` API to specify in an array which supplementary view we want to pin or make sticky. We can then use the Section view which wraps our content and specify either a footer or header.

** This code is working as of Xcode beta 2 **

As for using this in a `List` I'm not too sure, will be interesting to see the performance with `List` vs `Lazy...`

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      LazyVStack(spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [.sectionFooters]) {
        ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { index in
          Section(footer: FooterView(index: index)) {
            ForEach(0..<6) { _ in
              Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(height: 100).id(UUID())
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct FooterView: View {
  
  let index: Int
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Footer \(index)").padding(5)
    }.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0).foregroundColor(.green))
  }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5 / 2023 / iOS 16**

```
List {
...
}
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
     Text("App iOS Version 1.0.0 (xyz)")
         .font(.footnote)
         .foregroundColor(.secondary)
         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
         .textSelection(.enabled)
     }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overlay` on the `List`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0..<20, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Section {
                            Text("Item 1")
                            Text("Item 2")
                            Text("Item 3")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Updated at: 5:26 AM")
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                )
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "alarm")
            }
            Text("Content 2")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "calendar")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note:  overlay requires iOS 15